# Does get_global_id include offset?

Tags: c++, opencl

If I run kernel by calling clEnqueueNDRangeKernel with global work item offset, does get_global_id return offsetted value or I should offset it manualy?

```
size_t offset[1] = { some value};
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(..., &offset[0], ...);
```

The right way will be:
`int id =  get_global_id(0)`
or
`int id =  get_global_id(0) + get_global_offset(0);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `get_global_id(0)` does include the offset specified in `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`. For example, if you set the kernel offset to 50 and kernel range to 100, `get_global_id(0)` will count from 50 to 149.